# jScrollPane + Sticky navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, navbar, sticky

I'm trying to use both jScrollPane -or any other functioning custom scrollbar plugin- and a sticky nav bar at the same time, but it simply doesn't work, no matter what I do.

**JS FOR THE STICKY NAVBAR**

```
var num = 200; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

**JS FOR JSCROLLPANE**

```
$(function()
{
    $('#bodyID').jScrollPane();
});
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: do you have a css class defined for "fixed"? or are you trying to add a css property position: fixed.

Comment: The class fixed is defined.

Comment: do you have a sample of the html/css? hard to debug the issue from just js functions.

Comment: Sure thing : http://twenty-two.forumactif.org/
The red bar is the .navbar ofc, don't mind the colors though

Comment: this is probably because your $(window) isn't actually scrolling... the scroll is happening on your $('#bodyID')

Comment: The following code doesn't work aswell :

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        var navHeight = 100; // custom nav height
        if $('#bodyID').scrollTop() > navHeight) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('goToTop');
        }
    });
});`

Comment: you are still using $(window).bind(... this is binding the function to the scroll event of the window, but the window isn't scrolling. What is scrolling is the element that you set for jScrollPane(). You need to bind the scroll event function to that element.

Comment: I see. Tried that, still doesn't work :/ :

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bodyID').bind('scroll', function () {
        var navHeight = 100; // custom nav height
        if $('#bodyID').scrollTop() > navHeight) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('goToTop');
        }
    });
});`

Comment: Last (non-working) attempt -don't judge me-

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.navbar').offset().top;
    $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');
};`

i'm losing hope :(

Comment: i'm seeing the .navbar get a class .nb1 at 50px scrolled which causes it to "stick" (position: fixed). Is this not what you intend? I also tried adding the class "sticky" to the navbar and I don't see any css loading for it.